# Can I run Linux on N130 Network Terminal Thin Client?

Tags: linux

I've found this small device, named **N130 Network Terminal Thin Client** on [several webshops](https://www.google.com/search?q=N130%20Thin%20Client).

The datasheet says that it is running *"Embedded Eglobal operating firmware"*. I think, there is a good chance on that it is a minimal Linux distribution. So if it is, can I use it as a weak Linux server? Has anyone experience with it?

(P.S. I know what a thin client is, and I also know that a "firmware Linux" may have several restrictions.)

EDIT: http://www.eglobaltech.cn/ViewDetails67.aspx

EDIT2: Confirmed answer should describe that *how* can I use it as a weak Linux server, or tell *why* I can't do it. Also, I would be happy with a good datasheet, too.

Comment: Do you know which CPU/chipset it has? Without this, it's impossible to know whether Linux will run.

Comment: I don't want to install Linux on it, just use the one it is shipped with - assuming it runs Linux (if not, forget it).

Comment: Even if it runs Linux, most likely it will be an embedded distro which won't be much good for other uses beyond a thin client.

Comment: For this price, I want just stdlib and pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

Since it claims to run Windows XP it is likely to be x86-based. Running linux on it shouldn't be much more difficult than running it on a regular PC. Note however, that thin clients are usually booted from network (with PXE). *Embedded Eglobal operating firmware* doesn't say anything about Linux being available 0 more likely it will be just some sort of PXE environment.

> can I use it as a weak Linux server?

No or at least not directly - it does have any kind of local storage (USB, (S)ATA) or anything similar), hence there is no way to offer any services relying on **any** data, unless those would come over the network as well, in which case it doesn't seem to make much sense to have a thin client reserved for it. If you look for something with at least USB, your chances are much higher. You would probably still need to boot it from network though )unless it would be able to boot from e.g. USB, which however goes a bit against the basic idea of a thin client).

Comment: Neither my smartphone is designed to run my webserver, but it works. Both my Palm Pre (webOS) and all Android device (even without rooting).